# Ajax и работа javascript на load страницах

Tags: ajax, javascript

Не знаю как это правильно описать... на сайте при нажатии на ссылку происходит подгрузка контента в div, в этом контенте есть картинки, которые увеличиваются при нажатии (fancybox), но они не работают (js надо подключать внутри). Подключаю js - всё работает, но после нескольких переходов по ссылкам сайт начинает тупить (зависает при нажатии на ссылку). Как я понял, js накапливается и браузер не справляется.

Что посоветуете сделать?

Comment: Где-то выполняется цикл который грузит процессор.

Comment: Если сайт в паблике - дайте ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри на закрытие всех Timeout, при обработке запроса AJAX обычно ставиться Timeout на отлов не соединения с сервером, возможно ты их не обнуляешь и из-за этого "Накапливается" javascript . Во всяком случае это ест процессорное время.

Если хочешь чего-нибудь поконкретней - пиши свой код.